# xcode "copy files" build phase and symlinks

Tags: xcode, build, cmake, copy, symlink

I have a cmake projects which generates an xcodeproj. In this xcodeproject it copies openAL*.dylib into the Bundle's /Framework directory.

OpenAL (from ALSoft) has 3 .dylib files:

- a) openal.dylib, 17 bytes, symlink pointing to (b)
- b) openal.1.dylib, 22 bytes, symlink pointing to (c)
- c) openal.1.16.0.dylib, 483 KB, actual library

[image: openAL SDK in finder]

These files are copied in the "copy files" 
[image: xcode 'copy files' build step]

Now when I build my application the bundle looks like this:

- (a) openal.dylib, 22 bytes - which I assume is (b) from above
- (b) openal.1.dylib, 483 kb - which is probably (c)
- (c) openal.1.16.0.dylib - which is the library itself, 483 kb.

[image: Bundle with /Framework/openal*]

So apparently it only follow the symlink "1 level deep"... ?

How can I get xcode to "follow the symlinks to the end" ? I'd like openal.dylib to be 483KB in the bundle. From what I read on SO it should follow the symlinks, but shouldn't it do that recursively 'to the end' ?

Quick workaround would be to delete/overwrite openal.dylib with openal.1.16.0.dylib... any better alternatives to get xcode to follow the symlink-chain to the end ?